# Best data structure: arrays of dictionaries, arrays of objects?

Tags: python, numpy

I am converting to python and numpy from IDL (kinda like Matlab). This is kinda an open question about handling data. Maybe someone can help.

The usual situation with my data is that I have a fixed class of data, perhaps from a spreadsheet, database etc. I am trying to figure out what kind of data structures are best to use in python and numpy.

I know about the csv module and can use csv.DictReader() to read a spreadsheet. This reads line by line and makes a dictionary with the proper names from the spreadsheet header (first line).

```
f=open(file,'rU')
dat = csv.DictReader(f)
i=0
data=[] # makes an empty list
i=0
for row in dat:
    data.append(row)
    if i == 0 :
        keys=row.keys()
        print "keys"
        print keys
        print
    i=i+1

f.close()
```

First of all, that is kinda a lot of code to read a csv file into a list of dictionaries and key the keys. Is there a faster/better way?

But now, I wonder whether an array of dictionaries is really what I want. Should I make a class of objects and make this an array of objects? Or something else?

If I have my array of dictionaries, "data", I would get some "column" like
age=array([dat["age"] for dat in data])

Is that the right way to do it? Is there no way like "age=data->age" that would do it faster?

Would appreciate some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries not an array of dictionaries. It seems like you want a plain old array or maybe a recarray. Take a look at numpy.loadtxt or csv.reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it the way you are is OK, though your code can easily be made more concise:

```
data = list(csv.DictReader(open(file, 'rU')))
print "keys", data[0].keys()
```

Comment: Ok. Cool. But do, I need to close the file or will it close automatically if there is no file handle in scope?

Comment: @Dave31415: Always use this: `with open(file,'rU') as the_file:`.  Indent your `dat = csv.DictReader(the_file)` and all the rest inside the `with` and you are guaranteed that the file will be closed.

Comment: John Z's method also closes the file once the line with the open is executed. More generally a file will close when there are no more references to the file object (or at the end of the with block or when you call f.close()).

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with spreadsheet-type data a lot, I'd strongly recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), a Python package designed for this sort of thing. You just do:

```
pandas.read_csv(file)
```

That gives you a `DataFrame`, which does all sorts of fancy indexing, and is nice and fast.

Comment: Does that interact well with numpy or it supposed to be an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as how you explicitly mention using numpy, consider something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', names=True)
print data['item1']
```

Or

```
import numpy as np
item1, item2, item3 = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1).T
```

Where the format of `data.txt` is something along these lines (i.e. comma delimited).

```
item1, item2, item3
1.0, 2.0, 3.0
4.0, 5.0, 6.0
7.0, 8.0, 9.0
```

The first example uses structured arrays, while the second is just unpacking the columns (thus the transpose (`.T`)) into three variables.

Answer (score 0):

I always go with arrays of objects

Comment: Is there a quick way to automatically build a class from a csv file or do you have to build it manually by writing the code?